# Chord p2p distributed hash table (dht) implementation over http protocol

Tags: java, protocols, p2p, dht, chord

I have to implement the chord protocol over http as my project until now I've considered three ways:

1. Using jxta in java
2. Try to edit open-chord [which uses tcp/ip]
3. Coding from scratch using sockets in java

Any help?

Comment: [SO isn't a recommendation engine.](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/128562/175248)  But, have you looked into JXTA or Open-Chord?  Do you think you'd be able to reasonably program the sockets yourself in Java?  What have you tried?

Comment: i have no programming experience with sockets but i have tried running JXTA and its shell and also used open-chord shell...
i have no experience regarding p2p architecture

Comment: Regarding the "i have no experience regarding p2p architecture". Before committing to any of the proposed solutions, I will suggest you to check the existing literature on the topic: Chord, Can, Pastry, etc. and some surveys. While the implementation may be difficult, it is important to know how theoretically it should be working to understand some of the implementation choices.

Answer (score 0):

JXTA is a DHT plus many, many other things. JXTA is not going to help you; it is a "finished" P2P library.

Go for it, implement it yourself. The difficulty lies in getting the chord algorithm right, not the communication using http. Hacking (in the proper sense) open-chord or [chordless](http://sourceforge.net/projects/chordless/)may certainly help you.